# Preparing script for running on server

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, cross-browser-testing, server

I'm new here and want to share my experience with you. Till now I didn't have any experience in running my Selenium Java automation script on a server, but now I have a problem: I cannot find more information on **how to run the script before every deployment**.

I'm using TestNG, Maven, Selenium Webdriver, Java. POM, builder pattern. Generally, I want to implement multiple browser testing and handle photo upload. Also, because I`m not experienced I wanna ask, should I use RemoteWebdriver or I can run my script on a server only with Webdriver?

Comment: You need to better phrase your question and focus on one problem at the time. I'm quite confused after reading your post.

Comment: "before every deployment" of what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot find more information on how to run the script before every deployment.

If you want to run a script on a server, you would usually use a CI/CD tool to run the command that kicks off the tests (just like you would do locally). CI/CD is essentially "run this command based on this trigger" (deployment, schedule, etc.). You also use Windows Task Scheduler for learning how to run stuff overnight (schedule based).

> I want to implement multiple browser testing and handle photo upload

There are many ways of running your tests on different browsers. You'll need the different WebDrivers and a way to swap between them (setting the DesiredCapabilities). Your first test step would be opening the browser passed in by your @DataSource. There is a [screenshot](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TakesScreenshot.html) command in Selenium but if you are running on a server, you'll need to make sure that they are stored somewhere you can view them.

> should I use RemoteWebdriver or I can run my script on a server only with Webdriver?

RemoteWebDriver is the standalone-server.jar and that lets you register WebDrivers (browsers) with the Hub. This allows you to run tests on Edge or Safari from a (including but not limited to) linux host. That's basically how 3rd party services like SauceLabs and BroswerStack run.